# Exchange protocol at home LAN

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Usually I am using MS Outlook client at home in order to connect to some my POP3/IMAP/SMTP services. One day I decided that launching the outlook client on one PC at home is not comfortable: I have several devices in my home LAN, so I am willing to use one Windows PC for downloading e-mails and all other devices in my LAN (Windows and Android) would access these e-mails. The problem I see that the suitable software MS Exchange Server is installed on Windows Server OSs only (it cannot be Windows Workstation, am I right?) and exchange server itself is expensive.
My question: is there any other exchange-style software supporting ms exchange or another protocol, which may operate as e-mail gateway between Internet mail services and outlook clients. Or, is it possible simply to configure an Outlook client to play as a such gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a mail server on your home network. There are plenty of options like this which would allow you to use any client that can use at least SMTP/POP3. For example, there is a nice package called [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com) which has a very good free license. However, the one feature you would need to use it to pull in your mail from disparate sources is only available in the paid licenses for this particular product. It goes by the name, **POP Retrieval** in this package. This is what lets your internal mail server go out and poll for mail from typical mailboxes. There might be some free packages out there that have this feature, but I'm not familiar with any.

Another option that works with any SMTP/POP3 mail server is [GFI Mail Essentials](http://www.gfi.com/exchange-server-antispam-antivirus/mesfeatures.htm). It has a configurable polling feature that works with any mail server. Although again, this is a pay license product and has a number of other great mail filtering and management features. They refer to this feature as **POP3 Downloader** or **Pop2Exchange**.